# Options to increase the write performance in Redis

Tags: redis

My following Redis hmset for 30000 loop taking more than 6 seconds. And as the loop count increases, the result also increases. Is there any way to improve the write performance with in 5 seconds.

I have tried editing the redis.conf to disable save, rdbcompression, aof, etc. but still no luck.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='10.3.2.156', port=6379, db=2, decode_responses=True)
pipe = r.pipeline(transaction=False)

for x in range(30000):
    m = str(x)
    regactivekey = 'regactivetest||' + m
    pipe.hmset(regactivekey,{'lp': m, 'contact': '', 'regcontact': '''', 'src_ip': '127.0.0.1','regsrc_ip': '127.0.0.1',})

pipe.execute()
pipe.reset()
```

Comment: does the library you're using have a batching or pipelining API? it is *possible* that you might be able to get a boost by having multiple operations in flight (pipelining), rather than paying the latency cost on every operation

Comment: @MarcGravell The second line, and last 2 lines, suggest to me that OP is using pipeline already...

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the code above pipeline is being implemented. Any other hopes..

Answer (score 0):

`30000 / 6 = 5000` QPS. You haven't reached Redis' limit. Redis is much faster than that.

In order to achieve a higher QPS, you need to increase your concurrency. Instead of run the 30000 loops in a single python script, you can split the loops into 5 sub loops, and run each sub loop in a different python script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you tell me how to increase the concurrency instead of running different python scripts?

Comment: @PrathapMK Sorry, I'm not familiar with python. You might need to open another question for how to increase concurrency in a single python script.